# Qt add Yocto Zeus 5.4 toolchain

Tags: qt5, yocto

I compiled the Zeus version using Yocto in Linux Ubuntu 18.04 environment. But I cannot add the Zeus 5.4 toolchain to Qt5.
When adding the Qt version, I get the "qmake: execve: No such file or directory" error.
Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: what exactly have you done?

Comment: I tried to add Zeus 5.4 toolchain to Qt5.  I added compiler and debugger, but when adding the Qt version, I get the qmake error I mentioned above

Comment: how? what did you **exactly** do?